# Handling Invalid Json

Tags: python, json

I am getting an ill-formatted json , as the key "text" can have users comments, so I need to fix the issue with Json (with double quotes)

```py
{"test":[{"id":"1234","user":{"id":"1234"},"text":"test, "." test " 1234"","created":"2019-01-09"}]}
```

Tried below from another thread but not able to make it work.

```py
import json, re

while True:
    try:
        result = json.loads(test.json)   # try to parse...
        break                    # parsing worked -> exit loop
    except Exception as e:
        # "Expecting , delimiter: line 34 column 54 (char 1158)"
        # position of unexpected character after '"'
        unexp = int(re.findall(r'\(char (\d+)\)', str(e))[0])
        # position of unescaped '"' before that
        unesc = s.rfind(r'"', 0, unexp)
        s = s[:unesc] + r'\"' + s[unesc+1:]
        # position of correspondig closing '"' (+2 for inserted '\')
        closg = s.find(r'"', unesc + 2)
        s = s[:closg] + r'\"' + s[closg+1:]
print result

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    unexp = int(re.findall(r'\(char (\d+)\)', str(e))[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected Result:(check text: key data with escaped double quotes)

Or we can remove all double quotes after "text": & before "created" & then enclose the value in "text": key with a starting & ending " which would solve my issue

```
{"test":[{"id":"1234","user":{"id":"1234"},"text":"test \".\" test \" 1234\"","created":"2019-01-09"}]}
```

or

```
{"test":[{"id":"1234","user":{"id":"1234"},"text":"test . test 1234","created":"2019-01-09"}]}
```

Comment: Where does this JSON come from? Do you have access to the string before mounting the JSON? If so, you could just do `your_string.replace('"','\\"')` in the string.

Comment: @LucaBezerra I want those " escaped only on text: field as shown on the expected result.

Comment: @LucaBezerra not quite, as OP wouldn't want to escape the double quotes they *do* want. This would still require parsing the object as a string to fix it

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was asking if you have access to the string before mounting the JSON, aka the string that's in the `text` field. You could parse it before putting it into the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit that one line, so you can use a regex to match it, edit the value, and then join it back with the rest of the json string for it to be parsed

```py
import re
import json

json_str = '''{
  "test": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "user": {
        "id": "1234"
      },
      "text": "test "." test " 1234"",
      "created": "2019-01-09"
    }
  ]
}'''

lines = []
# match the text key
text_line = re.compile('^\s+\"text\"')

for line in json_str.split('\n'):
    # if a match happens, this will execute and fix the "text" line
    if re.match(text_line, line):
        k, v = line.split(':')
        # the slice here is so that I don't escape the wrapping
        # double quotes, which are the first and last chars of v
        v = '"%s",' %  v.strip()[1:-1].replace('"', '\\"')
        line = '%s: %s' % (k, v)
    # otherwise, carry on
    lines.append(line)

print('\n'.join(lines))

{
  "test": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "user": {
        "id": "1234"
      },
      "text": "test \".\" test \" 1234\"\"",
      "created": "2019-01-09"
    }
  ]
}

# Now you can parse it with json.loads
json.loads('\n'.join(lines))

{'test': [{'id': '1234', 'user': {'id': '1234'}, 'text': 'test "." test " 1234""', 'created': '2019-01-09'}]}
```

## EDIT: OP has indicated json is single line

There is some optimization that can be done, but you can find all of the keys in your json using `re`, and then parse it using a similar fashion as before:

```py
import re
import json

# Now all one line
s = '''{"test":[{"id":"1234","user":{"id":"1234"},"text":"test, "." test " 1234"","created":"2019-01-09"}]}'''

# find our keys which will serve as our placeholders
keys = re.findall('\"\w+\"\:', s))

# ['"test":', '"id":', '"user":', '"id":', '"text":', '"created":']

# now we can find the indices for those keys to mark start
# and finish locations to extract the value
start, finish = s.index(keys[-2]), s.index(keys[-1])

k, v = s[start:finish].split(':')
# replace v as before
v = '"%s",' %  v.strip()[1:-1].replace('"', '\\"')
# '"test, \\".\\" test \\" 1234\\"\\"",'

# replace string since it's immutable
s = s[:start] + '%s: %s' % (k, v) + s[finish:]

json.loads(s)
# {'test': [{'id': '1234', 'user': {'id': '1234'}, 'text': 'test, "." test " 1234""', 'created': '2019-01-09'}]}
```

As a note, this works for this particular use case, I can try to work out a more general approach, but this will at least get you off the ground

Comment: I donot see the output has any double quote escape in "text", parsing this still shows as Invalid json @c-nivs

Comment: It doesn't, because the output has been parsed as a dictionary, so everything is wrapped in single quotes. You just need them to be escaped for the string representation. Is your json *exactly* how it appears in the question?

Comment: @c-nivs Now I can see you code (print('\n'.join(lines))) working & printing with escape  , but this will only work if the Json comes as formatted with lines , which I did for better readability here, the actual json string comes in single line (now updated) , when the code is not working.

Comment: ok, that's an important distinction to make. I'll have to go back and see if I can re-work my solution

Comment: @c-nivs thanks, the latest code worked, just curious how to handle the same issue if the invalid json data has no fixed start & finish likebelow??

Comment: s = '''{"test":[{"id":"1234","user":{"id":"1234"},"text":"test, "." test " 1234""}]}'''

Comment: @rkj not sure what you mean by "has no fixed start and finish"